# can I change just a part of an image with onmouseover

Tags: html, onmouseover

I have mapped an image so if I click on a specific part it will go to a specific address. My image is divided in 6 so I have 6 `<area shape="rect" coords="a,b,c,d" href="link1.html" />`. Now I want to swap each part of my image  with another "small" image in case of a "mouseover"; if I use the onmouseover  the full image is swapped and not just the coords "a,b,c,d". I know how to do this using a table but I was wondering if I could do it another way? Thanks

Comment: Show your code to give something to work off of.

Comment: This is a fairly complex thing. Google it, try something, then come to SO when/if you fail.